# Spring Boot YARN override configuration, connect to Azure

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I'm using this simple [example](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-yarn-basic-single) to run Spring Yarn app against Hadoop on Azure.

The question is how can I set `fs.azure.account.key.aaa.blob.core.windows.net` property? Without it Spring YARN cannot deploy my jar file to cluster.

YarnConfiguration doesn't pick up my `yarn-site.xml` and `core-site.xml` files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

In `application.yml` `fsUri` should be without any ports and other stuff:

```
fsUri: wasb://zzz@zzz.blob.core.windows.net
```

YarnConfiguration picks every config file in `resources`.